# Manually emit a token with ANTLR

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, antlr

I'm having a bit of trouble manually emitting a token with a lexer rule in ANTLR.  I know that the emit() function needs to be used but there seems to be a distinct lack of documentation about this.  Does anybody have a good example of how to do this?

The ANTLR book gives a good example of how you need to do this to parse Python's nesting.  For example, if you see a certain amount of whitespace that's greater than the previous line's whitespace, emit an INDENT token but if it's less, emit a DEDENT token.  Unfortunately the book glosses over the actual syntax that's required.

EDIT: Here's an example of what I'm trying to parse.  It's Markdown's nested blockquotes:

```
before blockquote

> text1
>
> > text2
>
> text3

outside blockquote
```

Now, my approach so far is to essentially count the > symbols per line.  For example, the above seems like it should emit (roughly...) PARAGRAPH_START, CDATA, PARAGRAPH_END, BQUOTE_START, CDATA, BQUOTE_START, CDATA, BQUOTE_END, CDATA, BQUOTE_END, PARAGRAPH_START, CDATA, PARAGRAPH_END.  The difficulty here is the final BQUOTE_END which I think should be an imaginary token emitted once a non-blockquote element is found (and the nesting level is >= 1)

Comment: Scott, could you perhaps give an example of what you're trying to parse?

Comment: You mention Python in the question but you don't actually say what language you are using.  I gave an example that does this in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I did some research and found this: http://www.cforcoding.com/2010/01/markdown-and-introduction-to-parsing.html

I don't think ANTLR is really set up for this sort of task and trying to bend over backwards to do it isn't really worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Well if the token you want to emit is not defined by a lexer rule then you'll need to add a token section like so:

```
tokens
{
    MYFAKETOKEN
}
```

In your lexer you will still need a rule that tells the lexer when to produce this token.  A common instance is determining if something is an Integer or range or real value.

```
NUMBERS_OR_RANGE
: INT 
        ( { LA(1) == '.' && LA(2) == '.' }? { _ttype = INT; }
    | { LA(1) == '.' || LA(1) == 'e' || LA(1) == 'E' }? { _ttype = REAL; }
    )
| PERIOD 
    ( PERIOD { _ttype = RANGE; }
    INT (( 'e' | 'E' ) ( '-' | '+' )? INT )? { _ttype = REAL; }
)
;
```

Here you can see we match either an INT  and then lookahead, if we find a double period then we know that the INT is really an int and not a real.  In this case we set the variable _ttype to be INT.  If we find a PERIOD and then an 'e' we know it's a real.

The second case where we match a period we know that if the next char is a period, then we've got a range otherwise we've got a real.

We could use the `MYFAKETOKEN` type we defined above to assign to _ttype if that was appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty close to what I'm looking for... I have updated the question with a more concrete example, as requested.  If you have any insights, that'd be much appreciated!